# How to get first character beside underscore for a given string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

input:
string

```
'abc_def_ghk_lmn'
```

output:

```
dgl
```

Comment: Is underscores are fixed for a string?? and which dbms?

Comment: Underscore is not fixed ,it is for sql server @Rams

Comment: @AryanDas, try my `TSQL`. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Can the string end with an underscore ("Foo_")? Could there be two (or more) underscores in a row ("Foo__Bar___Voot")? If so, what is the expected result?

Comment: there wont be two underscore..@HABO

Answer (score 2):

You can try this (or even create a function):

```
 DECLARE @str varchar(250) = 'abc_def_ghk_lmn'
DECLARE @result varchar(250)='';

WHILE(charindex('_',@str)!=0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @position int = charindex('_',@str)
    SET @result += substring(@str,@position+1,1)
    SET @str = substring(@str,@position+1,len(@str))
END

SELECT @result
```

Comment: I'll make the same recommendation here as I did on the other answer. A `WHILE` loop is going to suffer performance issues as the `varchar` get larger, or, if there's a large dataset.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') is not null drop table #t
SELECT * into #t from (values (N'abc_def_ghk_lmn'), (N'a_f_k_n'), (null), ('____'), ('asasas'), ('a_sasas'), ('asas_')) T(val);

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  
         Cast(SUBSTRING(T.val, CHARINDEX('_',T.val,1) + 1, 1) as nvarchar(4000)) FC
        ,CHARINDEX('_', T.val, 1) CI 
        ,val
        ,0 [level]
    from #t T
    where CHARINDEX('_', T.val, 1) > 0
    union all 
    SELECT  
        Cast(T.FC + SUBSTRING(T.val, CHARINDEX('_',T.val,T.CI+1) + 1, 1) as nvarchar(4000)) FC
        ,CHARINDEX('_', T.val, T.CI+1) CI 
        ,val
        ,t.[level] + 1
    from CTE T
    where CHARINDEX('_',T.val,T.CI+1) > 0
)
, Res AS
(
    SELECT 
        * 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by val order by [level] desc) RN
    from CTE
)
SELECT * from Res where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) Function. Firstly because i don't know what version of SQL Server you are using, and secondly, the inbuilt function `STRING_SPLIT` (available in SQL Server 2016 onwards) doesn't include an Item Number value (thus how does one exclude the first result?):

```
SELECT (SELECT LEFT(Item, 1) 
        FROM DelimitedSplit8K ('abc_def_ghk_lmn','_') DS
        WHERE DS.ItemNumber > 1
        FOR XML PATH(''));
```

Edit:
Example with a dataset:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('asdgsad_sdfh_sadfh'),('_ashdf+ashd'),('jsda_sdkhfsdjf_654_asdfkhasd_567465413_kasbgdjkasdj')) V(S))
SELECT (SELECT LEFT(Item, 1) 
        FROM DelimitedSplit8K (S,'_') DS
        WHERE DS.ItemNumber > 1
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS FirstCharacters
FROM VTE;
```

Comment: @AryanDas Then you'd need to use a Splitter made by someone other than Microsoft. :) Jeff's is incredibly efficient, and there's a lot of detail on how it works and why it works as quickly as it does in the article of his I linked (along, of course, with the code for the SQL).

Answer (score 1):

Try this below

```
DECLARE @str TAble(String varchar(250)) 
INSERT INTO @str
SELECT 'abc_def_ghk_lmn_opq_rst_uvw_xyz'

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ''+LEFT(String,1) FROM 
(
SELECT Split.a.value('.','Varchar(1000)') As String,
 ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id FROM
(
SELECT CASt('<S>'+REPLACE(String,'_','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML )AS String
FROM @str
)as A
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('S') AS Split(a)
)dt
WHERE dt.Id <>1
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,0,'') AS  ExpectedColumn
```

Result

```
ExpectedColumn
--------------
dglorux
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this -...Always use **SET BASED Approach**

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE @x AS XML=''
DECLARE @ AS VARCHAR(1000) = 'abc_def_ghk_lmn_'
SET @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@,'_','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') Value FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t)      
)
,CTE1 AS 
(
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rnk FROM CTE
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(Value,1,1) v , rnk FROM CTE1
)
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(@,1) <> '_' THEN MAX(SUBSTRING(u,2,LEN(u))) ELSE MAX(u) END finalstr from (
SELECT  
        (
            SELECT '' + v  
            FROM CTE2 a               
            FOR XML PATH('') 
        )u
FROM CTE2 )x
```

**OUTPUT**

```
finalstr
---------------
dgl

(1 row affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(50)= 'abc_def_ghk_lmn',@Result VARCHAR(10)=''

WHILE CHARINDEX('_',@String)>0
BEGIN
    SELECT @Result=@Result + SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('_',@String)+1,1)

    SELECT @String=RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)- CHARINDEX('_',@String))
END

SELECT @Result FinalResult
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
FinalResult
dgl
```

Comment: I'd recommend against a `WHILE` loop; With a long string, or large dataset, performance will heavily degrade.

Comment: thanks.. it looks fine.. But is it possible without any loop?

Answer (score -1):

Use LEFT to get the left part and INSTR to find underscore and finally get your string:

```
SELECT LEFT(FIELD_1, CHARINDEX('_', FIELD_1) - 2) AS [ANY_ALIAS]
FROM TABLE_1;
```

EDIT: Now is MSSQL... ;D

Comment: `INSTR` isn't a T-SQL function.

Comment: I feel you did not understand the question...Please see the input and output.